# two way DataBinding not working properly in viewholder

Tags: android, android-databinding

So I have a viewHolder with a checkbox 
here is my viewModel

```
@Bindable
var itemIsSelected: Boolean = isSelected
    set(value) {
        if (field != value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.itemIsSelected) // this doesn't work
            notifyChange() // this one works
        }
    }
```

here is my viewHolder class

```
inner class SpecialityItemViewHolder(val binding: ItemSpecialityFilterBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(specialityItemViewModel: SpecialityItemViewModel) {
            binding.viewModel = specialityItemViewModel
            binding.executePendingBindings()
            this.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                binding.viewModel?.let {
                    it.itemIsSelected = !it.itemIsSelected // this doesn't trigger ui changes
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="packagename.ItemViewModel" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_margin_small"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_margin_small"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <Checkbox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:checked="@={viewModel.itemIsSelected}"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

so what happens is that the setting is working properly as in that when i press the checkbox it sets the backing field to the corresponding value
but when i set the backing field (notice code in bind function) it doesn't trigger ui change I know that calling binding.executePendingBindings() would solve the problem but my understanding is that notifyPropertyChanged(BR.itemIsSelected) should not need executePendingBindings call, Actually if i call notifyChange instead everything works properly ( but I presume there is performance issue here as it notifies change for all properties instead )

Comment: Why are you using two way binding `@={viewModel.itemIsSelected}` as well as `setOnClickListener()` to set the state?

Comment: @tynn because there is a textview next to it that i want it to toggle the checkbox plus even if that is the problem then why does notifyChange() work but not property changed

Comment: @AmgadSerry were you able to solve this? have you tried using **@get:Bindable** as the documentation shows in the sample for kotlin? 

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#kotlin

Comment: @AmilcarSerrano ended up using notifyChange but i will try changing Bindable to get:Bindable thx for the resource

Comment: I can not see any issue in your code, just let me know why did you referred `itemIsSelected` to `isSelected`?

Comment: @Khemraj when I used isSelected as a bindable variable name the generated BR reference stripped out the 'is' keyword and i didn't notice that and thought that was not generated so I used itemIsSelected instead but i fixed it later

Comment: Okay so this was issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel class have to extend `BaseObservable` class and using kotlin you have to use `@get:Bindable` annotation. If you don't want to use `BaseObservable` as a parent class then use `ObservableField<Boolean>()`. You find more information in https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#kotlin

Comment: it's alrdy using BaseObservable as parent class and @Bindable works fine and generates BR Class with appropriate value

Answer (score 0):

the view-model needs Kotlin annotations, else the annotation processor will ignore it:

```
class ViewModel : BaseObservable() {

    @get:Bindable
    var isSelected: Boolean
        set(value) {
            if (isSelected != value) {
                isSelected = value
                notifyPropertyChanged(BR.isSelected)
            }
        }
}
```

`it.isSelected` is easier to read than `it.itemIsSelected`.

Comment: when I used isSelected as a bindable variable name the generated BR reference stripped out the 'is' keyword and i didn't notice that and thought that was not generated so I used itemIsSelected instead but i fixed it later